# Boxplots from count table in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, ggplot2

I have a count table as dataframe in Python and I want to plot my distribution as a boxplot. E.g.:

```
df=pandas.DataFrame.from_items([('Quality',[29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]), ('Count', [3,38,512,2646,9523,23151,43140,69250,107597,179374,840596,38243])])
```

I 'solved' it by repeating my quality value by its count. But I dont think its a good way and my dataframe is getting very very big.

In R there its a one liner:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=1,y=Quality,weight=Count)) + geom_boxplot()
```

This will output:[!Boxplot from R[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5hUf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5hUf.png)

My aim is to compare the distribution of different groups and it should look like [image: this]
Can Python solve it like this too?

Comment: It looks like there is a `ggplot` interface for python, maybe the same syntax will work: http://ggplot.yhathq.com/

Comment: I updated my question and added the plot from R. It doesnt look very nice right now, but its just an example. I already saw ggplot, but I want to avoid using a lot of different packages. I thought pandas and matplotlib are quite powerful and I was wondering why it is not possible within these package....

Comment: Does the `boxplot` generated by using python be similar to the one obtained by R? I mean does the plot have to be same as the image you posted for the given data?

Comment: If I plot the  count table in python and it assumes that my columns are independent. So it return a boxplot for count and quality, which doesnt make sense in my case.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to look at here? The boxplot hereunder will return the following figure.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
df=pd.DataFrame.from_items([('Quality',[29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40]), ('Count', [3,38,512,2646,9523,23151,43140,69250,107597,179374,840596,38243])])
plt.figure()
df_box = df.boxplot(column='Quality', by='Count',return_type='axes')
```

If you want to look at your Quality distibution weighted on Count, you can try plotting an histogramme:

```
plt.figure()
df_hist = plt.hist(df.Quality, bins=10, range=None, normed=False, weights=df.Count)
```

[image: Histogramme]

Comment: I need a single boxplot, because I want to compare the distribution of multiple samples. I updated my question and added the plot I want to get at the end.